# On login with Facebook google API response not get assign to SESSION

Tags: php

I'm facing some problem in login with Facebook and Google API. I'm new to API integration, that's why I am not understanding the problem.

On index page I have login buttons on click API get called and and logged in successfully, I want to pass the login person's name to SESSION but when I clicked login all done very well, but the name not get assigned to SESSION, but I clicked twice on the button it works perfectly. I want it on single click.

On index page on click I took the response from API and send it on another page ajax2.php (for Facebook) this page just checks whether the user is exist or not if not enter that user to database and on this page this user name assigning to SESSION. and again on this page header set to index page.

But when it comes on index page it is not getting the SESSION value.

Code:

```
<script>
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      var user_name_facebook = response.name;
      //console.log('user : ' + fname);
      //console.log('User ID : ' + response.id);
      var user_id_facebook = response.id;
      //console.log('user id : ' + fid);
      if (user_name_facebook && user_id_facebook) {
           var i;
            <?PHP if(isset($a)) {
            }
            else {
                //console.log('for loop exicuted' + i);
             echo "window.location.href = \"https://example.com/ajax2.php? 
             user_name_facebook=\" + user_name_facebook + 
             \"&user_id_facebook=\" + 
              user_id_facebook;";
                }
                ?>
              }
           //console.log('facebook user:' + response.name);
          //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            //'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
        });
      }
    </script>
```

ajax2.php

```
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$user_name_facebook=$_GET['user_name_facebook'];
$user_id_facebook=$_GET['user_id_facebook'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
     else
     {
        //echo "connect";
     }

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from mytable WHERE user_id_facebook = 
'$user_id_facebook'");
      if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
         echo 'Username exist....';
      }
      else
    {
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO mytable SET

            user_name_google='".$user_name_facebook."',
            user_mail_google=' ',
            user_name_facebook=' ',
            user_id_facebook='".$user_id_facebook."',     
            key_val=0,
            user_coins=5");      
            mysqli_close($conn);

     }
header('Location: https://example.com/index_login.php');

?>
```

Comment: Side note: your `SELECT` query has a SQL injection vulnerability. Don't put this live until that is fixed.

Comment: ...so does the insert statement.

Comment: I've fixed this....the reason behind problem is the Load Balancer....thank you for reply.